# Why is the elapsed time in a loop not proportional to the number of iterations

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, time, benchmarking

I wrote the following code

```
#define TimeCode(Code) \
{\
    clock_t t1 = clock();\
    Code \
    clock_t t2 = clock();\
    double elapsed = (t2 - t1) * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;\
    std::cout << "Elapsed time " << elapsed << " sec" << std::endl; \
}

void loop(int nz)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5400; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5400; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < nz; k++)
                ;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    TimeCode(loop(17);)
    TimeCode(loop(34);)
    TimeCode(loop(649);)

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with `g++ -o main main.cpp`. The result is

```
Elapsed time 0.85579 sec
Elapsed time 3.14095 sec
Elapsed time 53.7562 sec
```

Then how come the elapsed time is not proportional to the loop size?

Comment: Because computers are incredibly, incredibly, incredibly, incredibly, incredibly, incredibly, incredibly, incredibly, incredibly, incredibly, incredibly, incredibly, incredibly, incredibly, incredibly, incredibly complicated.

Comment: There is the difference between wall-clock time and CPU time, when you are counting computational costs. CPU time is probably a better measure. You are counting the wall-clock time, which can include other things not really used for the loops.

Comment: @tinlyx According to the BSD manual, the `clock()` function determines the amount of processor time used since the invocation of the calling process. If the program uses only 1 thread, then `TimeCode` should be counting the CPU time, right?

Comment: @beave yes, as long as you're not on windows clock() counts CPU time.

Comment: It does not count it very accurately, though. And considering the effect of optimizations, the OP's bench is clearly meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be strictly proportional because of your loop structure:  for `loop(n)`, you perform:

- one initialisation of i, 5400 increments and comparisons for i
- 5400 initialisation of j, 5400*5400 increments and comparisons for j
- 5400*5400 initialisation of k, 5400*5400*n increments and comparisons for k

That's 29 165 401 fixed initialisations, 29 165 400 fixed increments and comparisons, and 29 160 000 * n iterations and comparisons.  So you can't obtain a proportional timing.

If you want to have something more proportional, you shall **make the `k` loop is the outside one**:

```
void loop(int nz)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < nz; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 5400; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 5400; j++)
                ;
}
```

I suggest you switch to the chrono [high resolution clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/):

```
#define TimeCode(Code, n) \
{\
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();\
    Code (n);\
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();\
    double elapsed = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count();\
    std::cout << "Elapsed time " << elapsed << " ms -> " << elapsed/n << std::endl; \
}
```

With these two changes, on my PC I obtain between 72 and 73 ms per iteration, in all the three cases.

The minor difference measured between for the three results is smaller that the clock resolution innacuracy (+/-15 ms on a windows platform).  To take this into account (but the inacuracy is platform dependent), I changed the output line in the macro to:

```
std::cout << "Elapsed time " << elapsed << " ms -> " << elapsed/n << " inaccuracy:" <<(elapsed-15)/n<<" - "<<(elapsed+15)/n<<std::endl; \
```

Here the final result:
[image]